# How to Concatenate SQL queries of Multiple Columns of Gridview into one column for search and filter?

Tags: php, gridview, yii2, yii2-advanced-app, yii2-basic-app

Let's say i have 5 columns merged to one in gridview,i would like to concatenate the column Filter function something like this

```
SELECT strcat(Column1, Column2, Column3, Column4, Column5) as MainColumnName.
```

and when i search i have to perform some query like this,

```
WHERE MainColumnName LIKE '%userinput%';
```

**Question:** How to implement it in the yii2,the result of the query will be reflected in dropdown filter in gridview.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is extend the functionalities of the search function so you can use the result in dataProvider

For this you should

setup your model   properly for get the concatenad  result eg using a getter

```
  /* Getter for  full name */
  public function getMainName() {
      return $this->column1 . ' ' . $this->column2 . ' ' . $this->column3 . ' ' . $this->column4 . ' ' . $this->column5;
  }

  /* Your model attribute labels */
  public function attributeLabels() {
      return [
          /* Your other attribute labels */
          'mainName' => Yii::t('app', 'Main Column  Name')
      ];
  }
```

Setup your search model  for filter and sort

```
  /* your calculated attribute */
  public $mainName;

  /* setup rules */
  public function rules() {
     return [
      /* your other rules */
      [['mainName'], 'safe']
     ];
  }

  /**
   * setup search function for filtering and sorting 
   * based on mainName field
   */
  public function search($params) {
      $query = YourModel::find();
      $dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
          'query' => $query,
      ]);

      /**
       * Setup your sorting attributes
       * Note: This is setup before the $this->load($params) 
       * statement below
       */
      $dataProvider->setSort([
          'attributes' => [
              'id',
              'mainName' => [
                  'asc' => ['column1' => SORT_ASC, 'column2' => SORT_ASC, 'column3' => SORT_ASC, 'column4' => SORT_ASC,  'column5' => SORT_ASC],
                  'desc' => ['column1' => SORT_DESC, 'column2' => SORT_DESC, 'column3' => SORT_DESC, 'column4' => SORT_DESC,  'column5' => SORT_DESC],
                  'label' => 'Full Name',
                  'default' => SORT_ASC
              ],
              'other_your_column'
          ]
      ]);

      if (!($this->load($params) && $this->validate())) {
          return $dataProvider;
      }

      ........

      /* Setup your custom filtering criteria */

      // filter by person full name

      $query->andWhere(" concat(column1, ' ', column2, ' ',column3, 
             ' ',column4, ' ',column5) 
                   LIKE concat('%','" . $this-mainName . "',  '%') ");

      return $dataProvider;
  }
```

And in your gridView

```
  echo GridView::widget([
      'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
      'filterModel' => $searchModel,
      'columns' => [
          ['class' => 'yii\grid\SerialColumn'],
          'id',
          'mainName',
          ['class' => 'yii\grid\ActionColumn'],
      ]
  ]);
```

You can find  some sample in this http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/621/filter-sort-by-calculated-related-fields-in-gridview-yii-2-0/

Comment: Getting this error,
syntax error, unexpected '', platformId, '' (T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING), expecting ',' or ')'

my sql query looks like this : $query->andWhere(' concat(classId, ' ',platformId, ' ',familyId, ' ',subFamilyName, ' ',variantName) LIKE "%' . $this-fullNamesCombo . '%"')

Comment: $this-fullNamesCombo   missing >   $this->fullNamesCombo

Comment: added > and still the same :|

Comment: answer  update with a different quotes sequence and concat for like too

Comment: Getting this error now,
SQLSTATE[42703]: Undefined column: 7 ERROR: column "classid" does not exist
HINT:  Perhaps you meant to reference the column "storeNames.classId".

Comment: and when i add storeNames before classId
i get 
SQLSTATE[42P01]: Undefined table: 7 ERROR: missing FROM-clause entry for table "storenames"

Comment: The Problem is the table is in a third Normal form, three of 5 columns are integers which are mapped to another table to get equivalent names.
So basically what i am trying to do now is searching for a string among a table with integers. I don't know how to correctly build an sql query.